# How to keep a user logged in with PHP Sessions for 1 year?

Tags: php, session

I'm currently using the following code:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 31968000);
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 31968000);

if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
    setcookie(session_name(), $_COOKIE[session_name()], time() + 31968000, "/", ".********.net");
}
```

I'm using that code for the "landing page" after someone logged in or registered successfully (after registration you'll be automatically logged in and transferred to the "landing page")

For some reason this works for a couple of minutes. I can close the App Safari and open it again for a few seconds and then maybe after half an hour it stops working. First I thought it would be working.

Any ideas?

Btw, 31968000 is more than one year of time in seconds.

Comment: A year is a loooong time, personally, I like to store sessions in the database for easy load balancing etc if I wanted a year-long session, id not implement the gc part and do it in a side-channel task: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php but tbh you should prob just set a cookie else after a year your session storage could be massive or have to never remove a users session completely just set them as logged out etc which is a bit convoluted

Comment: Leaving a user logged in for a year is an enormous hole in your security. One might question why you need a log in system at all. I strive to log my users out after a period of inactivity - usually about 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the properties session.gc_maxlifetime, session.gc_probability, session.gc_divisor and session.cookie_lifetime in the php.ini file in order to make it work.

Also it's important to restart the Apache server and php-fpm to load the edited php.ini file.

`service apache2 restart`

`service php7.3-fpm restart`

Comment: The properties mentioned in the starting post. So: session.gc_maxlifetime, session.gc_probability, session.gc_divisor and session.cookie_lifetime